# How to update any log or graph in output window during processing?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'd like to make auto test tool with Python. One thing I'd like to achieve is updating Test log in log window. However, all logs are displayed after finishing Test process. How can I show log during process?
In addtion, during processing, GUI stops working with error message"Not Responding". How to resolve it? thanks for your help in advance.

(Window 7, 64bit, Python 3.4, tkinter, matplotlib)

==========================================================================

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from time import sleep

root= Tk()
root.title("Auto Test")
root.geometry('300x700')
root.configure(background='white')

datac1_frame = Frame(root,bg="white",width=400, height=30)
datac1_frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor = W,padx= 5,fill=BOTH)

data1_frame = Frame(root,bg="white",width=400, height=280)
data1_frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor = W,padx= 5,fill=BOTH)

log_frame = Frame(root,bg="blue",width=400, height=80)
log_frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor = N,padx= 5,fill = Y)

#Output Box
logmes = Text(log_frame,width=800)
logmes.pack()

class autotest:
    def DUT_config(self):
        sleep(1)
        logmessage('DUT configuration')

    def measurement(self):
        sleep (2)
        logmessage('DUT is under measurement')

def freqentry(frame,text, command = None):
    label = Label(frame,text='Channel', bg = 'chartreuse',
                  width= 10).pack(side = LEFT, padx=10, pady = 2)
    entry = Entry(frame, width = 18, text = text,
                  justify = CENTER).pack(side = LEFT)
    button = Button(frame, text = "Run", bg = "lightsteelblue",
                    width = 5,padx=4, command = command).pack(side = LEFT)

def clickrun():
    logmessage ('button is clicked')
    for i in range(5):
        logmessage('# of try', i)
        at.DUT_config()
        sleep(1)       
        at.measurement()


def logmessage(*args):
    logmes.insert(END, args)
    logmes.insert(END, '\n')
    logmes.see(END)

#Channel, freq, Run button alignment
freqentry(datac1_frame, '2000MHz', clickrun)

## Data Gathering
f_0 = Figure(figsize=(2.5,2.5), dpi =100)
a_0 = f_0.add_subplot(111)
a_0.xaxis.grid(True)
a_0.yaxis.grid(True)
a_0.plot ()

## Display on the plot
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f_0, data1_frame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT)

at = autotest()

plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow.

First issue I see is your **handling of scope**. I suppose you posted this as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If this is your complete code, please be advised that there are some issues you should resolve. Your function `def logmessage(*args)` uses the variable `logmes` which is defined outside your function **and** additionaly used in other functions as well.

Like in most programming languages, the scope of a function limits access of variables in python. If you want to use the `logmes` listbox "globally" declared, you need to tell that to the functions as well by declaring the variable global inside the function (sample below)

```
    # We are inside the main routine here - global scope
    root= Tk()

    log_frame = Frame(root,bg="blue",width=400, height=80)
    log_frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor = N,padx= 5,fill = Y)

    #Output Box
    logmes = Text(log_frame,width=800)
    logmes.pack()

    # Here come functions having their own scope
    def logmessage(*args):
        # Use variables from global scope - global declaration
        #################################
        global logmes
        #################################
        logmes.insert(END, args)
        logmes.insert(END, '\n')
        logmes.see(END)
```

Using global variables is often seen as some kind of a bad habit, as it reduces the ways of reusing your code in other purposes. I *personally* prefer using classes in modules and putting everything that belongs together inside a class. This results in a module structure like

- Module Header:               e.g. commentary lines, version, author, shebang, etc.
- Import Section:              here i import whatever i need
- Class and Function Section:  here i define my classes and functions
- Main Routine:                starting with `if __name__=="__main__":` I start processing if the script is called and not imported, **function *calls*** happen only here

Unfortunately I see a second issue as well - inside your "*Import Section*" you are importing `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. Later on in your main routine you are calling `plt.show`. I am not using matplotlib often, but if I remember it correctly, you first define a **`pyplot Object`** and then call the `show` routine on the object, not the Module itself.

Do you receive any error messages inside your python console output? (Supposing you are calling the script from the commandline) or do you call it by double-clicking it? How do you store the file? I am focusing on the *file-extension* here, as it **does** make a difference if you store it as ***.pyw** or ***.py** in having or not having a console output window.

Another issue I just recognized is your class definition. As the [documentation of the class module in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) states out, a class is sth. that supports

> two kinds of operations: attribute references and instantiation.

You are using your class as sth. like a *function wrapper*. You are not using inheritance nor are you declaring an `__init__` funcionality to **instantiate** class variables.

It is no question that python gives you the **ability** to do so, but please keep in mind that your use of a `class` does more do sth. a `module` would do. Declare a namespace for certain functions that do not need more than the parameters passed (if any).

I do really recommend you have a very close look at the [class documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). This really helps improving your code and reduces the necessity to be slowed down by asking questions and waiting for replys on stuff the documentation can tell you directly and using simple examples.

Please do not see my last comment as any offense as this is definitely not intended here, just as a recommendation to help you improve in your work.